# Scapy does not see UDP package

Tags: python, sockets, udp, scapy

I have a snmptrapd-server running inside WSL2 (under docker) and I am trying to send UDP-package to this server via Scapy (from Windows host).

This is how I run snmptrapd-server inside WSL with Docker:

```
sudo docker run -it --rm -p 162:162/udp --name snmptrapd sig9/snmptrapd
```

This is how I make my UDP-request with Scapy:

```
answered, _ = sr( 
    inet.IP(dst="172.31.175.161") /     
    inet.UDP(sport=sport, dport=162) /     
    Raw(         
        b'\x30\x43\x02\x01\x01\x04\x06\x70\x75\x62\x6c\x69\x63\xa6\x36\x02'         
        b'\x04\x10\xfc\xb4\xbe\x02\x01\x00\x02\x01\x00\x30\x28\x30\x0d\x06'          
        b'\x08\x2b\x06\x01\x02\x01\x01\x03\x00\x43\x01\x00\x30\x17\x06\x0a'         
        b'\x2b\x06\x01\x06\x03\x01\x01\x04\x01\x00\x06\x09\x2b\x06\x01\x06'         
        b'\x03\x01\x01\x05\x01' 
    ), 
    timeout=5, 
    verbose=2
 )
```

Here `172.31.175.161` is an IP of my "WSL-machine". `sport` is an any unused port (`27450` in this case).

I can see that my UDP-request was delivered to snmptrapd-server (server logs my request):

```
2023-05-18 mshome.net [UDP: [172.31.160.1]:27450->[172.17.0.3]:162]:
DISMAN-EVENT-MIB::sysUpTimeInstance = Timeticks: (0) 0:00:00.00 SNMPv2-MIB::snmpTrapOID.0 = OID: SNMPv2-MIB::coldStart
```

And also I can see the request (and response too) in Wireshark:
[image]

But for unknown reason I cannot see UDP-reply in Scapy:

```
Begin emission:
Finished sending 1 packets.
....
Received 4 packets, got 0 answers, remaining 1 packets
(<Results: TCP:0 UDP:0 ICMP:0 Other:0>, <Unanswered: TCP:0 UDP:1 ICMP:0 Other:0>)
```

Comment: Scapy doesn't find responses if you build a packet using `Raw`. You should parse the raw data first as an SNMP packet